# Unity: i need to apply a force on a rigidbody in the direction of my camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my current code uses the world directions but i need it to use the direction of my camera (ignoring the y axis)

here is my current code:

```
{
    public GameObject Cam;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float movespeed = 10f;

    private float xInput;
    private float yInput;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ProcessInputs();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //movement
        Move();

    }

    private void ProcessInputs()
    {
        xInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        yInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }
    private void Move()
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(xInput, 0f, yInput) * movespeed);
    }
}
```

i think the problem is in the last line, i tried add relative force but since this is attached to a ball that rolls it doesn't work i have been trying for a few hours to get this to work but its probably really easy and i just have a massively smooth brain.
i have searched through every tutorial i can find, every reddit post and even page two of google. i cannot find a solution to this incredibly simple task. i am stitching several tutorials together to make my Frankenstein code monster because im new to coding with unity.

i am looking for the ball to move in the direction the camera is facing when i press w and left of the camera when i press a same for d and s. im getting the ball to move but when i turn my camera (using a separate fully functioning script) the ball keeps its axis of movement.

Comment: you need to explain in detail the the outcome you want vs the outcome you obtain. Why the `yInput` is in the z coord like this `new Vector3(xInput, 0f, yInput)`? is it for a specific purpose for the outcome you are after? You can check [Transform.Forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html), to obtain the local z axis in the world space. With `.up` and `.right` you can obtain any of the 3 local axis in the world space. Also check [Transform.InverseTransformDirection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly the same a few years ago, this is the (cleaned) snippet of code that should do what you want. `absoluteMovement` is the vector in world position that needs to be added to your object. Like you in your example I removed the Y-Axis from the equation.

```cs
var movementRelativeToCamera = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) * speed;
var cameraLookingDirection = cameraObject.transform.rotation * Vector3.forward;
cameraLookingDirection = new Vector3(cameraLookingDirection.x, 0f, cameraLookingDirection.z).normalized;
var absuluteMovement = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, cameraLookingDirection) * movementRelativeToCamera;
```

**Explanation**:

- [Line 1] You first get the amount to move (multiplied by a `speed` variable)
- [Line 2-3] You get the view-direction of the camera, remove the Y-Axis and normalize the vector again
- [Line 4] you create a quaternion (rotation) from your standard-forward-vector to your camera view direction (`Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, cameraLookingDirection)`) and apply it to your relative movement, to rotate it from a 'normalized' view in the direction in which your camera looks.

Note: Since I did this in some old Unity version, it could be that Unity's API has changed since then, but I doubt that on basic functionality like vectors and quaternions.

#### Edit: A few more sentences about quaternions

Quaternions are used to store and make calculations with rotational information. You could say a quaternion is a 'rotation'. You can apply such a rotation to a vector by multiplying it with the vector:

```
rotatedVector = quaternion * unrotatedVector;
```

If you want to go deeper on how quaternions work, there are quite some youtube videos on that topic. That said: you do not need to understand how they work to do basic operations with the, like the on in our example here. You should just not try to set a quaternions values by hand if you don't know how they work, they are not really 'human-readable', so you probably wont end up with what you expect. But [Unity provides a nice amount of helping functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) like `Quaternion.FromToRotation`, `Quaternion.LookRotation` or `Quaternion.AngleAxis` to name a few.